# Select non existing Numbers from Table each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, range, recursive-query

I‘m new in learning TSQL and I‘m struggling getting the numbers that doesn‘t exist in my table each ID.

Example:

```
CustomerID Group
1          1
3          1
6          1       
4          2
7          2
```

I wanna get the ID which does not exist and select them like this

```
CustomerID Group
2          1       
4          1
5          1
5          2
6          2
....
```

..

The solution by usin a cte doesn‘t work well or inserting first the data and do a not exist where clause.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Count non-existing values? I'd say that would always be 0.

Comment: i edited my post *select

Comment: It is possible but is not how SQL works. SQL is designed to get **existing** data.

Comment: not existing means getting the next higher number, I need the available CustomerIDS each group

Comment: Do you mean existing customers, but not in that group?

Comment: Isn't `CustomerId` 7 missing from `Group` 1? Or has it been banished to [Group W](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Group%20W%20Bench)?

Comment: What do u mean? The Id 7 exist already. I wanna select all ‚available‘ customerid‘s - which are not included in the first screen.

Comment: Exactly. There is a customer 7 and they aren't in group 1. Why is 7 not _available_ for group 1? Did you neglect to mention that a customer can only be in one group? If a customer 8 existed in group 1 would customer 7 have to be "eliminated"?

Comment: Ohh I got it! No, it should not be eliminated.  I wanna get those not existed or ‚available‘ ID‘s for each group. When CustomerID 7 is NOT in group 1 But it is in Group 2, then i wanna get the CustomerID 7 only in the Group 1, only that group, which doesn‘t contain that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live with ranges rather than a list with each one, then an efficient method uses `lead()`:

```
select group_id, (customer_id + 1) as first_missing_customer_id,
       (next_ci - 1) as last_missing_customer_id
from (select t.*,
             lead(customer_id) over (partition by group_id order by customer_id) as next_ci
      from t
     ) t
where next_ci <> customer_id + 1
```

Comment: thanks!! can I ask you, why u working with lead? and selecting the first missing and the last missing id?

Comment: @Leo96 . . . Because it does what you want.  `lead()` gets the next id.  The question is whether that is one more than the id in the current row.

Comment: One ID can be in several groups. U mean that?

Comment: @Leo96 . . . That has nothing to do with the answer.  The `partition by` limits the comparisons within a single group.

Answer (score 0):

Cross join 2 recursive CTEs to get all the possible combinations of `[CustomerID]` and `[Group]` and then `LEFT` join to the table:

```
declare @c int = (select max([CustomerID]) from tablename);
declare @g int = (select max([Group]) from tablename);
with 
  customers as (
    select 1 as cust
    union all
    select cust + 1 
    from customers where cust < @c
  ),
  groups as (
    select 1 as gr
    union all
    select gr + 1 
    from groups where gr < @g
  ),
  cte as (
    select *
    from customers cross join groups
  )
select c.cust as [CustomerID], c.gr as [Group] 
from cte c left join tablename t
on t.[CustomerID] = c.cust and t.[Group] = c.gr
where t.[CustomerID] is null
and c.cust > (select min([CustomerID]) from tablename where [Group] = c.gr)
and c.cust < (select max([CustomerID]) from tablename where [Group] = c.gr)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=35a331744d12396fa00bbcc827411b40).
Results:

```
> CustomerID | Group
> ---------: | ----:
>          2 |     1
>          4 |     1
>          5 |     1
>          5 |     2
>          6 |     2
```

Comment: Edit: It's working fine, thanks. The issue is the perfomance. Can I declare above the IDs and a group? For instance selecting the not existing id's between 800 and 850 for group xy. Gonna work a little bit on that exmaple and see further.

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e278706e87639d0de4c781b622cc875

Comment: It won't work using separate table inserting the data while having millions of data in my db...

Comment: What do you mean separate table? If you have such a large table make sure to have indexes for both columns.